# display a div using javascript and onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css, show

I've read lots of posts on this but I'm still struggling. I'm trying to show and hide a div class using some simple java. I can get it to work in JSFiddle but not on my live site.

Here's the code I'm using. **HTML first**

```
<div id="mydiv1">
    <div id="mydiv-container">
        <div id="mydiv-content">
            <h1>Here's The Popup 1</h1>
            <br>Click the link to close.
            <br>
            <a href="#" onclick="show('mydiv2')">Open 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2"  style="display:none">
    <div id="mydiv-container">
        <div id="mydiv-content">
            <h1>Here's The Popup 2</h1>
            <br>Click the link to close.
            <br>
            <a href="#" onclick="hide('mydiv2')">Close 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function show(target) {
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Can't workout why it wont switch divs on live server.

Comment: where did you defined the functions??

Comment: Did you check if `id`s `mydiv1/mydiv2` are unique

Comment: this  code is working fine check you id (mydiv2) is not repeating.

Comment: Just make sure the functions are known before assigning them. if I change from including the JS in the <head> to onLoad, it will say the functions aren't defined. https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/x9yh3yr9/

Comment: add return false after onclick, ie, onclick="show('mydiv2'); return false" and    onclick="hide('mydiv2') return false."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem on your server is the `id`s i.e. `mydiv1` and `mydiv2` are not unique. The `id`s are repeating.

Check on your server if `id`s are not duplicating.

**id should always be unique.**

You can use `Web Developer` extension on Firefox and Chrome.
To get duplicate `id`s on page

1. Install `Web Developer` on your browser
2. Open options by clicking on `Web Developer` icon
3. Click on `Information` tab
4. Click on `Find Duplicate Ids`

Hope this will help.

To Download toolbar:

Chrome: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/?src=userprofile

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. Did as you suggested and the id's are repeating. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Don't repeat in your code. :). Change ids of these elements

Comment: Me being dumb - I've now removed duplicate id's but still having problems showing second div. The url for this site is www.picassosparadise.com

Comment: Hmmm, If I view the JS file in web developer it shows a html file!

Comment: Okay, fixed the error with the js file not loading, that was a dodgy url .